# Meaning of 那就一样来一个吧 in the conversation

Tags: meaning-in-context

```
A: 这儿的辣子鸡丁和糖醋鱼都不错。

B: 那就一样来一个吧。
```

（1） How can 那就一样来一个吧 be translated into English?

（2） What is the meaning of 来? I think it means "bring to (us)".

Answer (score 2):

那就一样来一个吧 is a shortened sentence. In day to day speech, it is a common practice to omit some elements that are presumed to be understood or strongly implied.

You can understand the sentence as "**那就**(每)**一样**(种类)(都給我)(各)**来一个吧** " --> "Then bring me one each from each kind"

- "每一样" (each kind ) refers to 辣子鸡丁 and 糖醋鱼 which are the two kinds of dishes mentioned in the previous sentence, therefore, no need to repeat them in the next sentence. If three kinds of dishes were mentioned, then 每一样 (each kind) would refer to all three
- "給我来一个XX" = "bring me a XX"

A detailed sentence would be: "那就給我辣子鸡丁和糖醋鱼各一个吧" (Then give me spicy chicken and sweet and sour fish one dish each)

Similarly:

*"那就每样給我来两个吧" would mean "Then give me spicy chicken and sweet and sour fish two dishes each"*

Note: Shorten 那就(每一样)来一个吧  to 那就(每样)来一个吧 is more clear than 那就(一样)来一个吧 because '一样' might be interpreted as "the same"

*The above answer is based on Standaed Written Chinese (SWC)*

Answer (score 2):

(1) 那就一样来一个吧 means "give me one of each"

(2) [Collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/chinese-english/%E6%9D%A5) has an entry for this usage:

> 3. (泛指做事)
>    ⇒ 请来碗面条。 (Qǐng lái wǎn miàntiáo.) A bowl of noodles, please.
>    ⇒ 你累了，让我来。 (Nǐ lèi le, ràng wǒ lái.) You're tired — let me do it.

It does not mean "come" here.

Answer (score 1):

> （1） How can 那就一样来一个吧 be translated into English?

It means ***Then [I will have] one of each***.  The important part is "一样来一个" means "one of each".  In this case, B is ordering one 辣子鸡丁 (spicy chicken) and one 糖醋鱼 (sweet and sour fish).

The 那 might be translated to "then", and indicates it's in response to A's comment.  I believe the 就 is just for emphasis.

> （2） What is the meaning of 来? I think it means "bring to (us)".

I'm not precisely sure why, but 来 is commonly used to order food (among other phrases), e.g.

> 请**来**一个包子 ([source](https://www.nidezhongwen.com/ym0121/))
> I'd like one steamed bun
>
> **来**一个吧 ([source](https://elementarychinese.com/order-chinese-food-stress-free/))
> I’d like one.

I feel 来一个 is shorthand for 给我来一个, which means something like "give me come one [dish]" which is ungrammatical in English, but it's possible to give verbs in Chinese.  Maybe it can be translated to "cause one [dish] to come (for/to me)".

Answer (score 1):

来 is used as this sense:

> 6 . 表示做某个动作（代替意义具体的动词）
>
> 你搬不动，我来吧 / 唱得真好，再来一个 / 不要跟我来这一套。

For translation, you can take any verb that can make sense.  In your example, *take, bring, etc* can work.